# Visual Studio 2015 and Logitech SetPoint

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, logitech

As [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100229/is-there-a-back-button-hotkey-for-navigation-in-visual-studio-2008), I've been using Logitech SetPoint to map some mouse-buttons to short-key combos in VS2008 in order to have some better navigation.

[image]

However, I've recently switched over to VS2015 (on a Windows7 machine) and now wanted to port the same settings.
The problem is, that when I add the VS2015 IDE via the "Add..." button and the path

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"`

it *does* appear in my list at first:

[image]

But when I "OK" out (and/or "Apply" the setting), it does not seem to persist. Entering the setup again, the entry just dissappeared again completely.

I know that people hat issues with SetPoint not being *accepted* by VS2015 unless started as admin ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38167677/1302888)), but this is different. I seem not ot be able to "add" a setting for VS2015 in the first place.

Experimenting with admin privileges of SetPoint and/or VS2015 and/or switching off UAC did not yield any working solution for me yet.

Any help would be highly appreciated, including information from people just verifying they *do* have a working setup - in order to possibly compare differences.

---

For completeness sake: I should be on the "actual" version of set-point according to the updater:
[image]

---

And for clarity: I have no problem adding other applications and short-cuts, including those which are launced with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Set-Point differentiates the application solely by the executables name. This can be seen when editing the config-XML file located under

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Logitech\SetPoint\user.xml`

which, f.e. reads:

[image]

As a result, adding VS2015 with the path

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

was simply ignored because it already had

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

### The good news is:

**The mapped bindings will be applied for *both* VS versions when they are run.**

(  Provided that the ["administrative privileges issue"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38167677/1302888) is not preventing it. )